# Does SplMinHeap or SplMaxHeap implement Traversable interface logically?

Tags: php, heap, spl

I noticed that `SplMinHeap` or `SplMaxHeap` implements the `Iterator` interface, which implements `Traversable` interface, so I can use `iterator_to_array (Traversable $iterator) : array` or `foreach` syntax to iterate any instance of these two classes.

```php
SplMaxHeap extends SplHeap implements Iterator , Countable {

SplMinHeap extends SplHeap implements Iterator , Countable {
```

But when I iterate an instance of SplMinHeap/SplMaxHeap repeatedly, I got **an empty array** after the first iteration. It looks like that the first iteration broke the inner structure of SplMinHeap/SplMaxHeap.

```php
<?php
$minHeap = new SplMinHeap();
$minHeap->insert(15);
$minHeap->insert(5);
$minHeap->insert(10);

foreach ($minHeap as $val) echo $val, PHP_EOL;

var_dump(iterator_to_array($minHeap));  // empty array
var_dump(iterator_to_array($minHeap));  // empty array
```

Yes, we can traverse/iterate this data structure as its class declared, **but only once**. Is it logical?

Comment: Yes I think its logical. When you try iterate heap values, probably it extracts value that means remove value after usage. https://www.sitepoint.com/data-structures-3/